Не удаётся подключится к боту и базе данных асинхронно
Пытаюсь соединить Aiogram3 и asyncpg, но столкнулся с недостатком понимания асинхронности.
Я пытался сделать запуск БД и бота таким образом:
dp = Dispatcher()
adb = DB(DSN)


@dp.message(CommandStart)
async def start(message: Message):
    async with adb.pool.acquire() as conn: # взять подключение из пула и потом вернуть обратно;
        x = await conn.fetch('SELECT * FROM manga;')
    print(x)
    await message.answer('Работает.')


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)

    await adb.connect()
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

class DB:
    def __init__(self, dsn):
        self.dsn = dsn
        self.pool = None

    async def connect(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(self.dsn) # создать пулл подключений;

    async def close(self):
        await self.pool.close()

Но я понял, что асинхронностю тут и не пахнет, две корутины блокируют друг друга и работают последовательно, а не асинхронно.
Я в принципе не нашёл достойных примеров применения asyncpg, хотя вроде как эта библиотека вне конкуренции по скорости среди всех подобных, так как использует не текстовые инструкции, а обращение к байт коду через C.
Если есть какие-нибудь best practices, я буду очень рад почитать.

Почему вы хотите сразу подключиться к базе данных? Нельзя ли создавать подключение во время обращения к методу, а после закрывать его?

asyncpg - это правда крутая библиотека, но она не распространена, т.к. содержит достаточно урезанный функционал по сравнению с конкурентами. А такие скорости обычно никому не нужны в проектах.

Ben Puls, я хочу использовать именно пулл подключений, чтобы снизить потребление ресурсов и времени на открытие и закрытие подключения каждый раз, а так из пулла вытягивается и возвращается.
Я пытался сделать методы для fetch и execute внутри класса, но тогда для транзакции придётся делать отдельные методы. Если мне необходимо сделать несколько запросов в рамках одной транзакции, чтобы предотвратить ситуации, когда одни данные внеслись, возникла ошибка, вторые данные уже не внеслись, а первые не удалились.
Поэтому мне удобнее контролировать пулл через класс, а создавать запросы отдельно

У меня мало опыта в асинхронном программировании, поэтому пока неудобно работать внутри async def, поэтому могу допустить ошибки и не лучшие практики.

Проблема решена созданием задач:
async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)

    task1 = asyncio.create_task(adb.connect())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(dp.start_polling(bot))

    await task1 
    await task2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Также, используя gather, удалось сделать то же самое, но короче и проще.
async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)

    task1 = asyncio.create_task(adb.connect())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(dp.start_polling(bot))

    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Но даже с таким подходом иногда возникали ошибки, что нет такого метода .acquire(), потому что БД не успевало создать пулл подключений, когда бот уже запускался. Или вроде того.

Возможно такой способ поможет решить проблему. За основу я взял ваш код, поэтому класс будет таким же.
class DB:

    def __init__(self, dsn):
        self.dsn = dsn
        self.pool = None

    async def get_connection(self):
        return self.pool

    async def connect(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(self.dsn)
            
    async def close(self):
        await self.pool.close()

Указываем параметры подключения, в нашем случае dns postgres://user:password@host:port/database.
db = DB("postgres://user:password@host:port/database")

Из переменной db обращаемся к методу connect(), для того чтобы создать пул, а затем обращаемся к get_connection(), чтобы получить пул. А затем можем работать с базой данных.
async def main():
    await db.connect()

    pool = await db.get_connection()

    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        print(await conn.fetchrow("""SELECT * FROM users"""))


asyncio.run(main())


Насколько я понял, это буквально то же самое, что я делаю, только с дополнительным методом и чуть длиннее конструкцией. async with adb.pool.acquire() as conn: Здесь я напрямую через экземпляр обращаюсь к pool и использую его в контекстном менеджере, вместо возвращения этого же pool, но через метод.

Моя проблема заключалась именно в асинхронном подходе без блокировщиков для работы одновременно и с ботом, и с базой данных.  Это минимальный пример кода, а в реальности там будет очень много хэндлеров, функции и прочего. Переношу проект из синхронный telebot версии в асинхронную aiogram.
